# Connecting to SSL Site using cURL, connection refused for lack of password/key

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I'm attempting to connect to a SSL protected website using cURL. I've used OpenSSL to extract the SSL certificate and convert it to a pub file. I've also used OpenSSL to extract the public key into a pem file. Yet I keep getting the following message in return: "unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass pharse?)

Here is are my cURL options

```
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestParameters,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestParameters)
        ),
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:$password",
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $certLoc

));
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE` is an *SSH* option, not SSL.

Comment: whoops. In my attempt to fix the problem I just started scanning options from the documentation and applying them. Evidently I didn't read what I copied carefully enough. I'll remove that options from the post